# Specify file and working directory when launching Rstudio

Tags: command-line, rstudio

I launch Rstudio from the command line (on Linux). I want it to start with a certain file, and in a specific working directory (so that the relative paths in my script work).

How can I accomplish this?

- `rstudio-bin .` launches with the correct working directory, but I still have to click around to open the file
- `rstudio-bin my-file.R` launches with R script open, but the working directory is wrong (`~` rather than current dir)